# Git command output string to another command input SHELL

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jenkins

I want bash or shell script for this requirement

Git branch --show-current - $INPUT  take it as input

git checkout master

git cherrypick $(INPUT)     -- I want to use this input here

So how to do it in shell or bash script

Answer (score 0):

Do you wish to save value of command `Git branch --show-current` in variable `INPUT` ? If that is the case, you can try this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT=$(Git branch --show-current)
git checkout master
git cherrypick $INPUT
```

It saves the value of `Git branch --show-current` in INPUT so it can be used later on in the script.